Approximation of bounded borel measurable function with continuous function such that $\int^{1}_{0}|\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x}|^2dx < 1$

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a bounded borel measurable function. Does there necessarily exist a continuous function $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ such that $\int^{1}_{0}|\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x}|^2dx < 1$?

Honestly, I'm not sure where to begin. I know that continuous functions are dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ but I don't know if you can approximate $f$ "fast" enough to "beat" $\frac{1}{x}$. On the other hand, I understand that $f$ can't be continuous if I want to come up with a counterexample, but I'm not sure how to continue from there.
